# Generating a random link through Javascript for online survey

Tags: javascript, random

I have read the post about Generating a random link through Javascript/HTML. 
[Generating a random link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37751759/generating-a-random-link-through-javascript-html?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa).

I'm just wondering how to make sure each URL could appear at the same ratio? For example, I have four URLs, and each of them will appear 50 times randomly.

URL 1: 50 times
URL 2: 50 times
URL 3: 50 times
URL 4: 50 times

Thanks in advance.

Comment: how do you know if it appears 50 times? Sounds like you want a weighted random number. But to know if it hits X number of times would require you to store stuff on the server for its usage.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz Did we read the same question? Has nothing to do with generating a GUID.

Comment: [`Generate A Weighted Random Number`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435183/generate-a-weighted-random-number)